# how to enter a character in Java and store it to stack

Tags: java, stack

```
import java.util.*;

public class StackDemo {

   public static void main(String args[]) {

   Stack st = new Stack(); //creation of stack

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   String str;
   str = scan.next(); //inputting a character

   st.push(str); // push it to stack

   System.out.println("Elements in the stack: "+st); //print the elements of the stack.
  }     
}
```

Now I'm trying to find a way in entering multiple characters and store it to the stack.

Example:

c

h

a

r

Elements in the stack: c, h, a, r

Is there a way?

Comment: Put the `scanner` inside a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of `while` loop & do something like this :-

```
          while(scan.hasNext()){
           str = scan.next(); //inputting a character
           if(str.equals("exit")) // input `exit` and loop will break
               break;
           else 
           st.push(str); // else it will keep adding elements in stack
           }
```

Replace the below code of yours with the above code :-

```
   str = scan.next(); //inputting a character
   st.push(str); // push it to stack
```

Console Output :-

```
HI
HELLO
BYE
exit
Elements in the stack: [HI, HELLO, BYE]
```